# How to redirect all traffic in eth0 to eth1 and back

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, iptables, nat

I have a Ubuntu box with eth0 and eth1.

How can I redirect all the traffic coming from eth0 to eth1 and back?

Should I do DNAT and SNAT like below or just forwarding or both ?

**Edit**

My case is like this A-B-C, 3 machines. Both A & C in different network. B have two nic one is  A's network (eth0) and other in B's network (eth1). I can't set B as the gateway in A nor B.

Below is how this was achieved by iptables on host B: **SOLUTION**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp ! --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination eth1IP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Have excluded port 22 so that SSH traffic is spared from the rules and my ssh to host C works.

Comment: Are those different Ethernet ports using different hardware?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Both are in different network. A --- B --- C. A and B(eth0) in same network. B(eth1) and C in same network. If A wants to talks to C then it's only possible via B.

Comment: If you can't change the routing tables on A and C, then you can't get either of them to send their traffic for each other by way of B, even if you had B acting as an IP forwarding router. But what about the default gateways on the networks that A and C are on…can you change the routes on those gateways? If those gateways each know that B provides a route to the other subnet, then those other gateways can ensure that traffic between A and C gets rerouted through B.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the netmasks are correct and do not overlap, you do not need to use DNAT or SNAT, you simply need to ensure that:

1. Each computer has a default gateway set through the Linux box, or has a route to the other network via the Linux box.
2. The Linux box has forwarding enabled – uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_fortward` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reboot (or `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to do it temporarily).
3. Ensure the firewall allows forwarding (`iptables -vnL` and check that the `FORWARDING` rule has no chains and is set to default `ACCEPT`). This is, I believe the default.

Comment: I can't change the default gateway in other machine.

Comment: Why not bridge eth0 and eth1 so they appear as a single network?